# Generating UR5 Robot Package with Moveit Setup Assistant

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I created moveit package with MSA tool, It gave me a edited URDF for UR5 robot and created its own launch and config directory with neccesary files. And after that I would like to simulate this system with RViz and Gazebo. (I know that you dont have to create a Moveit package, there are UR5 Repositories that already did the work, but my case is different).

I run empty.world gazebo with:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch paused:=true use_sim_time:=false gui:=true throttled:=false recording:=false debug:=true
```

Add up my urdf file in to the system:

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file place/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_description/urdf/gaze.urdf -urdf -x 0 -y 0 -z 1 -model ur5
```

And when I run my launch file with Rviz

```
<launch>

  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find gaze_demo_moveit_config)/config/joint_names.yaml"/>

  <include file="$(find gaze_demo_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" >
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
  </include>

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
    <rosparam param="/source_list">[/joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>

  <include file="$(find gaze_demo_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
  </include>

  <include file="$(find gaze_demo_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

My controller.yaml

```
controller_list:
  - name: gaze_controller_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: True
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - wrist_1_joint
      - wrist_2_joint
      - wrist_3_joint
```

It gives me errors such as:

```
[ERROR]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ elbow_joint shoulder_lift_joint shoulder_pan_joint wrist_1_joint wrist_2_joint wrist_3_joint ]
[ERROR] : Known controllers and their joints:

[ERROR]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

And this:

```
[ERROR]: Action client not connected: gaze_controller_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
```

I checked my controllers.yaml many times. but everything seem fine. After that I saw some people in answers.ros talks about follow_joint_trajectory topic. when I checked my rostopic I couldnt find that topic? I believe it can be the problem. How can I add that service?

Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330009/generating-ur5-robot-package-with-moveit-setup-assistant/) by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-05**:
I don't have time for a full answer right now, but in short: you're not starting any controller. Gazebo only provides a stand-in for your hw, not the control(ler) interface.

Take a look at the `ur_gazebo` packages and how they load the appropriate `ros_control` controller(s).

**Comment by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on 2019-08-06**:
Thanks I Added a comment and upvote you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I guess you first need to add the joint_trajectory_controller configuration as described in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller).  Also, don't forget to get the controllers running! Add them in your launch files.

This should solve your problem I guess.

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2019-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on 2019-08-06**:
Hello yes I found the solution as descriped in this tutorial. I created a package for gazebo launch similar to the tutorial, I made the neccasery launch files for Joint trajectory Controller and finished the tutorial. Now I can control robot with Rviz. However I cannot control it with Moveit Python script.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K09E-_2M-vQ&list=PLK0b4e05LnzbrLrLhOhSvLdaQZOsJl59N&index=13